# Setting Background Image in Joomla

Tags: css, image, templates, joomla, background

I was trying to set a background image in a joomla template in header position, I modified the file template.css and it displayed the background image but not correctly, I could see only the a part on the left and the right of the new backgournd image and the rest is hidden (the white background covered it), I dont know what I did wrong:

Here is the template URL link: 
http://vitadorotest.hhc-netzwerk.de/

Here is my CSS coding part :

```
body.font-size-is-default {
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height:19px;
    color:#8f8f8f;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background:url(../images/background.jpg) 50% 0 no-repeat #fff !important;
    height: 95px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1087px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the real problem,,
`white_tail.gif` is a while image that cover the the defined id with while background.

```
#rt-top, 
#rt-header, 
#rt-menu, 
#rt-showcase, 
#rt-feature, 
#rt-utility, 
#rt-breadcrumbs,   
#rt-maintop, 
#rt-main, 
#rt-mainbottom{
   background:url(../images/white_tail.gif) 50% 0 repeat-y;
}
```

just comment it like

`/*background:url(../images/white_tail.gif) 50% 0 repeat-y;*/`
and see the result.

Answer (score 0):

I added some backgrounds using the added tag on the article home page of http://colorta.com & its working.

```
<div style="background-image: url(images/banners/myimage.jpg); ">
```